# Getting schedular overweight error while doing runtime upgrade

Tags: runtime-upgrade, substrate-node, blockchain, democracy

I am trying to do a runtime upgrade through democracy referenda and the steps I performed are as follows:

1. create pre-image.
2. submit pre-image through democracy .
3. endorse
4. voting .

After this I am getting event of schedular overweight. I have done runtime upgrade through democracy before also but this is the first time I got this error can someone help me with this.

[image]

Comment: Is your chain a parachain?

Comment: @AurevoirXavier it is a relay chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the relay chain case you can overwrite the weight of the runtime upgrade by wrapping the `system::set_code` extrinsic into a `utility::with_weight` and overwrite the weight to something small.
We use this approach in Polkadot/Kusama to ensure that the upgrades do not hang with such an error.